# Android APK File can't be installed on Huawei phone; Signature error

Tags: android, android-studio, installation, apk, signature

I have an Android App and I create an APK-File for it with Android studio and when I try to install it on my Huawei P8 Lite ALE-L21 I get an error saying

```
"app.apk: signatureerror. Installation failed".
```

I tested it on the devices and it worked perfectly.
Does anybody know a solution to this issue or had this happen before? Would be really helpful if you have some advices.

Comment: Please post your manifest file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While creating a signed apk make sure you have selected both **V1** & **V2** in Signature Versions.

[image]